# How to set up localhost server and database for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, tcp, localhost

I am new to PostgreSQL, and I want to use it on my personal laptop for personal projects. I use SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio at work, coding-wise I'm ok but I need some help with setting up the localhost on my laptop.

So I downloaded PostgreSQL and installed it along with pgAdmin that came with the package.

During installation, it asked me to create a PostgreSQL superuser password, which I did.

Then I tried creating a new server using pgAdmin as follows:

General Tab:

> Name: localhost
>   Server Group: Servers
>   Connect Now?: check

Connection Tab:

> Host name/address: localhost   Port: 5432
>
> Maintenance database: postgres
>
> Username: postgres
>
> Password: [blank]

But when I click save I'm getting an error message:

> Unable to connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host
>   "localhost"(::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could
>   not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the
>   server running on host "localhost"(127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

Also tried replacing the password field with the Superuser password, getting the same error message.

Would greatly appreciate it if anyone offers any insights into this problem, I might just be a noob when it comes to server setups...

Thanks,
Mike

Update:
I believe there's a service I need to start as suggested by @Scott Moniz. I went into services.msc, tried to start the service **postgresql-x64-10 - PostgreSQL Servier 10**, and I got this error message:

> "The postgresql-x64-10 - PostgreSQL Server 10 service on Local
>   Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if
>   they are not in use by other services or programs".

I then tried editing the property of the service, by changing the **Log on as** option to **Local System Account** and tried starting the service again, still got the same error message.

I'm using Windows 10 Home edition, it this helps to resolve the issues in anyway

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Please mark as answered if it helped :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942125/backup-restore-postgresql-database-and-setup-localhost-environment-with-larave

Comment: Please check this link I am giving https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942125/backup-restore-postgresql-database-and-setup-localhost-environment-with-larave

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the database service is running and listening? 
CLick Start>Run> type services.msc

Look for a postgresql service - if it does not say started right click it and click Start.

Alternatively you can restart your computer and the service should start if it is set to 'Automatic'

Comment: Hey Scott thanks for your answer. I tried what you said here, the service is set to Automatic by default, and tried to turn it on, it gave me a prompt saying the service can only be started when certain programs start running. I restarted my computer and check the service again, it still shows Automatic.

Comment: I got some insights from others, and I'm now looking at the pg_hba.config file, maybe there's ways to set up the localhost by edit this file. I also heard that postgreSQL and Windows inherently doesn't work well together, postgreSQL works better with Linux

Comment: Weve run postgresql and windows with no issue. It would still say automatic - but  you should see 'Started' next to it. Hopefully you are able to resolve. Good luck

Comment: Thanks again Scott, I don't think it says "Started", but I'll take a look at it again tonight, other that than, do you think the settings I have in pgAdmin are correct?
Best

Comment: Without looking at the settings Im unsure. The server should start with default settings. I would suggest uninstalling the postgresql server and restarting

Comment: I tried to start the postgresql-x64-10 - PostgreSQL server 10 service again, and it gave me an error message "The postgresql-x64-10 - PostgreSQL Server 10 service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs". 
I then tried logging in as Local System Account, still got the same message.