# Backup & Restore PostgreSQL database and setup localhost environment with laravel in windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql, laravel-5, pgadmin-4

1) open C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\pg_hba.conf

change: 
       host           all             all             ::1/128                 md5

to

host           all             all             ::1/128                 trust

2)open pgAdmin & create a localhost server with username postgres and password will empty

/* For taking a backup or restore a dump of existing database name */

open cmd line and go to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin and press enter

and type below command as required

Take Backup :
      pg_dump.exe -U postgres -d dbname -f D:\Backup\

```
 or direct take backup using pgAdmin backup option and store in D:\Backup\<backup-file-name>  

hint: backup file should be tar or dump type
```

Restore Backup : pg_restore -U postgres -d dbname -1 D:\Backup\

3) In laravel code folder open .env file and add DB_SSLMODE=disable

4) in laravel  code folder open config/database.php and for 'pgsql' array

```
 replace

     'sslmode'=> 'require', 

 to    
    'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE','require'),
```

Answer (score 2):

## How to Backup PostgreSql DB In Laravel

1. install laravel package using composer.

   `composer require spatie/laravel-backup`
2. insert the following line to your backup controller.

   `use Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\PostgreSql;`
3. write the following code in your backup controller.

   ```
   date_default_timezone_set('EST');

   try {
       $this->info('The backup has been started');
       $backup_name = 'backup-' . date('c')  . '.sql';
       $backup_path = 'app/backups/' . $backup_name;
       PostgreSql::create()
           ->setDbName(env('DB_DATABASE'))
           ->setUserName(env('DB_USERNAME'))
           ->setPassword(env('DB_PASSWORD'))
           ->dumpToFile($backup_path);
       $this->info('The backup has been proceed successfully.');
   } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
       logger()->error('Backup exception', compact('exception'));
       $this->error('The backup process has been failed.');
   }
   ```